# What about ios push notification disabled for my app?

Tags: java, ios, push

I'm sending push notifications on devices in Java with [Javapns](http://javapns.googlecode.com).

When a user uninstalled my app and I send a push to him, I'll find this user in the feedback service, that's ok.

But how it works if the user disabled my app notifications ? How can I know it on server side ?

The app can know it (with UIRemoteNotificationType) and warn the server with a get/post but is there a way to know it on the server ?

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) isn't clear enough about push notifications sent and user deviced push notifications disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. Except for the feedback that you described, you will know nothing. Even if the user installed your app and enabled notifications, it may never get the notification and you won't know about this.